# Monitoring network namespaces

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-namespaces, iproute

Is there a way to monitor netns creation/deletion in the kernel?

iproute2 provides means to monitor this but it does by using inotify, looking for creation/deletion of a netns fd in `/var/run/netns`.
Often times a netns is created without an entry in `/var/run/netns`.

Ideally a netns creation/deletion notification should be available via netlink message from the kernel but it does not seem to be the case.

Watching for `/proc/<pid>` creation and then stat(ing) `/proc/<pid>`/ns/net does not seem like a feasible option.